# ruby on rails, undefined method 'belongs to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am new to ror and I got an error

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :photos, :price, :title, :user_id, :category_id
  attr_accessor :user_id, :category_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :catgory
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  after_validation :reverse_geocode
end
```

The call stack is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `belings_to' for #<Class:0x00000003b1c418>):
app/models/item.rb:5:in `<class:Item>'
app/models/item.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/item_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Your error mentions `belings_to` - are you sure that's typed correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `belings_to' ``

it should be `belongs_to`, check your code

Comment: fixed it. a stupid mistake. thank you